# Extract Month in sql and adding 1

Tags: sql, oracle, extract, to-date

If I add 1 to extract(month from date), then does the result become 13 or 1 (January of next year)

I have the below code:

```
(extract(day from sysdate) >=1 and extract(month from sysdate)=12) and (targstartdate >= to_date(((extract(month from sysdate))|| '-1-' ||             (extract(year from sysdate)+1)) , 'mm-dd-yyyy') and targstartdate <= to_date(((extract(month from sysdate)+1)|| '-1-' ||(extract(year from sysdate)+1)) , 'mm-dd-yyyy')
```

Comment: Please share the dbms as well

Comment: `select extract(month from sysdate)+10
from dual` Gives me 13 as `3+10`

Comment: yes sir, is month 13 will automatically becomes month 1 because there is no month 13.

Comment: Added `oracle` tag based on the combination of `to_date()` and `sysdate`

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? What is the _underlying_ problem you are trying to solve? Maybe there is a much better to do what you want, but that's impossible to answer with the information given. Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 1):

You can use MOD

```
MOD(extract(month from sysdate)+1,12) + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get the month number of the next month, flip your logic.  Instead of extracting the month number and adding 1, add one month to the date then extract the month.  See the difference below.  The second adds one month, then extracts the month of 1 (for January).

```
select extract( month from to_date('12/15/2017','MM/DD/YYYY')) + 1 from dual
union all
select extract (month from ADD_MONTHS(to_date('12/15/2017','MM/DD/YYYY'),1)) from dual;
```